# How do you initialize a String in java?

Tags: java, string

I have taken to using setters instead of putting arguments into the default constructor because it helps me organise my code better

The problem is that the only variable on a project I am doing is a String and I am not sure whether I should be initializing it in the declaration (as a global variable?), in an setter instance method or whether to initialise it in the class constructor.

I am wondering if there could be anything problematic about this set up whether the instance is not initialised until it's setter is used:

```
class MyClass{

  private String myString; 

  public MyClass(){

  }
  public void setStuff(String s){ 

    this.myString=s;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "global variable" since Java doesn't have global variables.

Comment: What you are calling a global variable in called `instance variable` in Java.. And Instance variables are initialized to their default value.. (Here your String variable will be initialized to null)

Comment: You should read [the Sun/Oracle Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), specifically this one on primitive data types.

Comment: oh ok thanks for pointing that out about the instance variable. I had it as myString = null; and it compiled but I am not sure why not the "new" keyword? @RohitJain

Comment: Java Strings are immutable, so there is no real need for using 'new' keyword for a String. Use literals instead (double-quotes).

Comment: If you're a certain type of purist you can use `myString = new String("Some string");`, but it causes the unnecessary creation of a new String object (vs using the literal value directly).

Comment: I see what you mean. I chose initialize it as null in the end. myString is a file name in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by global variable? Is it truely a variable that is the same inrespective of the object that is created? If so it should be static

```
private static String myString = "str";
```

If it never changes then it should be final and is then a global constant

```
public static final String MY_STRING = "str";
```

This can then be public and accessed via

```
MyClass.MY_STRING
```

If it is only applicable for each object of the class that is created then either initialise it in the constructor or in the declaration

Comment: Thanks, this it doesn't answer the question but it's really good point of information. Would you mind if I appended your answer a bit to complete it?

Comment: yep go for it :) @Magpie

Answer (score 7):

Why not just initialize as:

```
private String myString = "My string";
```

The easiest way possible.

Comment: Or `myString = null;`, if it initially is null, or `myString = "";`, if you want to initialize to a null (empty) string.  (But all class and instance variables are initialized to `null` implicitly, so `myString = null;` is redundant except for local variables.)

Comment: @HotLicks. Wouldn't it be initialized to null automatically.. As it is instance variable??

Comment: @RohitJain -- Yeah, I was just getting around to adding that point.  But sometimes it's nice to state the initialization to null as a formality.

Comment: So then why not just leave my default constructor empty?

Comment: @Magpie.. You can do that.. That's no problem.. And one more thing.. You never define a `default constructor`, rather a `zero-arg constructor`.

Comment: @Magpie -- You might, for instance, have 12 instance variables, ten of which *do* require actual initialization.  By stating the initialization of all 12 you can more readily assure that you didn't miss one that should have been initialized.  Just a trick to fool yourself into not making errors.

Comment: @RohitJain can you elaborate on that pleasE?

Comment: @Magpie.. `Default constructor` is actually a `zero-arg constructor` only, but it is defined by `Compiler`.. But as and when we define our own `zero-arg constructor`, we don't call it `default`.. It is just `zero-arg constructor`.. I just wrote that because I saw you telling your zero-arg constructor as default..

Answer (score 3):

Well, it really depends on what that variable is and what it's going to do.

Is it a constant? If so, you can initialize it like this:

```
private final String myString = "foo";
```

Is it meant to be an instance variable? If so, you should go for something like this:

```
public MyClass(string myString)
{
    this.myString = myString;
}
```

If it's some kind of optional property, the way you have now might be fine as well. In the end, it really all depends on what you're going to be doing with that variable.

Comment: If it's constant, it should _be_ a constant: private static final.

Comment: I'm wanting to use setters is why not.

Comment: What do you mean you're "wanting to use setters"? We have no idea what you're trying to do, so it's impossible for us to tell the best way for you to do it. There is a time and a place for using mutators; you shouldn't "want to use a setter" you should use what is best for each situation, which sometimes will be a setter and sometimes will not.

Comment: Wouldn't it be constant anyway, strings are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

Just like you have it looks good to me.  BTW, "global varible" can be misleading cause it may imply that the var is public whereas it is private but accessible outside via a public getter/setter.

But to initialize a String, the simplest way is:

```
private String foo = "some string";
```

Comment: are you serious?  it is the name of the String variable

Comment: @Magpie -- "foo" (along with "bar") is a traditional name for a variable in an example program.  Comes rather indirectly from the military slang acronym FUBAR -- F(ouled) Up Beyond All Recognition.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what `MyClass` will be doing.  Most of the time, it's best to have a constructor that will initialize private variable and to also have a getter and setter for it.

One reason is what if `MyClass` has a method `foo` which needs `myString` to be initialized and you forgot to call `setStuff`?